# Медленный тайп в IE (selenium grid)

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, браузер, selenium-grid

Добрый день. В интернете есть много статей про медленный тайп в IE через selenium grid. Основная описываемая проблема - это использование x64 IEDriverServer.
В моем случае используется версия x32 и тайпает текст он быстро, но после прогона какого то количества тестов (~1.500) он начинает медленно тайпать текст и остальные тесты просто падают по таймауту.
Решение этой проблемы - перезагрузить комп с нодой или просто сделать логаут юзера, снова под ним зайти и поднять ноду. К сожалению это очень долго, если учитывать что таких нод может быть порядка 6-8. 
Возможно кто то встречался с подобной проблемой и знает как ее решить? Или знает более адекватный способ привести в порядок ie, без перезагрузки компа/вылогинивания юзера? 
Желательно какой то способ, который можно было автоматизировать, что бы не пришлось заходить на каждую ноду по отдельности

Используется IEDriverServer х32 версии 3.7.0

Comment: Какой перевод на русский у транслита "тайп" по Вашему?

Comment: печатать, напечатать

Comment: С контекста Вы не поняли? может тогда не стоит оставлять бессмысленные комментарии?

Comment: Не понял. Русский знаю. Английский знаю. А вот англо-русская смесь для меня загадка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из основных бед Selenium grid - деградация производительности после длительного аптайма. Может ваша проблема связана только с IE, а может еще и с гридом как таковым.
Есть различные аддоны для грида, чтобы бороться с этим. Вот например: https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras
Можно настроить рестарт ноды после определенного количества тестов и пр.